# Connect OpenLayers3 Client with QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, server

at the moment I am developing a map editor on a  web.

After researching at the internet about map clients, I decided to use OpenLayers3 client because it is very simple an has all the tools i need for my project.

So, my question is:

```
 - It is possible to connect OpenLayers3 Client with QGIS Server?
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can for example use the WMS-Layer from your QGIS-Server in ol3:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/0woc6xL3/